# Unable to install Pykerberos on Macos due to clang command failure

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, macos, kerberos

I want to install `requests_kerberos` so that I can import `DISABLED` and `HTTPKerberosAuth`. When I enter the command on my Mac's terminal: `pip3 install requests_kerberos`, I get an error about failed build of `pykerberos`. I get the same error when I try to install `pykerberos` directly using the command `pip3 install pykerberos`:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-record-qux6yptd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

The completed error trace is:

```
Collecting pykerberos
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/b8/1ec56b6fa8a2e2a81420bd3d90e70b59fc83f6b857fb2c2c37accddc8be3/pykerberos-1.2.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pykerberos
  Building wheel for pykerberos (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-wheel-fg2zm2wd --python-tag cp38
       cwd: /private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/
  Complete output (107 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'kerberos' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/kerberos.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/kerberos.o
  In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
  #error Unsupported architecture
   ^
  In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
  typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
  typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
  typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
  typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
          ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
  typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
          ^
  note: '__int128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
  typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
          ^
  note: '__uint128_t' declared here
  In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
  In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
  #error architecture not supported
   ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 errors generated.
  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pykerberos
  Running setup.py clean for pykerberos
Failed to build pykerberos
Installing collected packages: pykerberos
  Running setup.py install for pykerberos ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-record-qux6yptd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: /private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/
    Complete output (107 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'kerberos' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c src/kerberos.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-x86_64-3.8/src/kerberos.o
    In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:63:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:807:2: error: Unsupported architecture
    #error Unsupported architecture
     ^
    In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:11:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include/limits.h:21:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/limits.h:64:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/limits.h:8:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:33:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/_types.h:34:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:27:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:55:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_blkcnt_t;      /* total blocks */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:56:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_blksize_t;     /* preferred block size */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:57:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_dev_t;         /* dev_t */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:60:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_gid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:61:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_id_t;          /* [XSI] pid_t, uid_t, or gid_t*/
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:62:9: error: unknown type name '__uint64_t'
    typedef __uint64_t      __darwin_ino64_t;       /* [???] Used for 64 bit inodes */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:68:9: error: unknown type name '__darwin_natural_t'
    typedef __darwin_natural_t __darwin_mach_port_name_t; /* Used by mach */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:70:9: error: unknown type name '__uint16_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint16_t      __darwin_mode_t;        /* [???] Some file attributes */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:71:9: error: unknown type name '__int64_t'
    typedef __int64_t       __darwin_off_t;         /* [???] Used for file sizes */
            ^
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:72:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_pid_t;         /* [???] process and group IDs */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:73:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_sigset_t;      /* [???] signal set */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:74:9: error: unknown type name '__int32_t'; did you mean '__int128_t'?
    typedef __int32_t       __darwin_suseconds_t;   /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__int128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:75:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_uid_t;         /* [???] user IDs */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:76:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_useconds_t;    /* [???] microseconds */
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:71:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_types.h:43:9: error: unknown type name '__uint32_t'; did you mean '__uint128_t'?
    typedef __uint32_t      __darwin_wctype_t;
            ^
    note: '__uint128_t' declared here
    In file included from src/kerberos.c:17:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/Python.h:25:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:64:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/_stdio.h:75:
    In file included from /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h:31:
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include/machine/types.h:37:2: error: architecture not supported
    #error architecture not supported
     ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 errors generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-install-hpm0d0z0/pykerberos/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/wp/w5ztm8tj0mq99fprhvys5f540000gr/T/pip-record-qux6yptd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I tried looking at other similar errors but none of the resolutions worked, such as `brew install openssl` was successful but did not resolve the error. How do I install `pykerberos`?

## Update 1

I tried setting env variables for `OpenSSL` but failed:

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install requests_kerberos
```

It throws the same error.

Comment: What version of MacOS are you using? It indicates in the message something about MacOs10.15 which is Catalina if I'm not wrong...

Comment: I'm getting the same error when trying to install 'pip3 install aws-adfs' that depends on pykerberos package.

Comment: I've been chasing down if I'm missing a base library like openssl@1.1 or krb5 from my brew installs but not finding what's missing so far.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in macos 10.14 to get pykerberos to install in base python38.

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip3 install pykerberos
```

I had done brew installs of openssl and krb5 already done.

```
brew install krb5 openssl
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is still prevalent in macOS Monterey 12.1.
Using the following made no difference:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip3 install pykerberos
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30842358)